# Magento 2.3 | Found 2 elements with non-unique id #fulltext

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Getting following errors at admin->order->grid, under console:

```
Found 2 elements with non-unique id #fulltext
Found 2 elements with non-unique id #sales_order_grid.sales_order_grid.listing_top.listing_paging_sizes
```

Above errors, making browser comparability issues while printing invoices on IE and safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, got it fixed.
Need to override following file:

```
/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml
```

Old code:

```
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <settings>
            <sticky>true</sticky>
        </settings>
```

New code:

```
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <settings>
            <sticky>false</sticky>
        </settings>
```

Thanks,